# What do the numbers under your ammo count mean?

Tags: the-division

In the Division, I know what almost all UI elements mean, except the number below the ammo/clip count, shown below as "20" (highlighted section 2). Even the site I stole the image from neglected to explain what this value meant. Can anyone fill the gap in my knowledge? May seem like a stupid question, but I can't find what it means anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the number of rounds in the clip of your 'other' weapon.

As it's quicker to change weapons than reload, it's helpful to know how many rounds you've got left.

To test, fire all the rounds in your first weapon, then immediately switch to your other weapon, and you'll see the counter turns red and shows `00`.

Here is a picture of my character using a sidearm with both weapon clips empty.

[image: Both empty clips]

Comment: What's more is, if you have your sidearm out, that display will show the remaining ammo in whatever weapon you'll switch back to by pressing "Y" (presuming you're playing with a gamepad).

Comment: @JimDagg It's clearly different on PC as demonstrated in the picture: you can see two ammo counts in addition to the sidearm's. I assume the difference boils down to not having buttons to pull out each specific weapon so your only choice is to switch back to the previous weapon.